# How get all rows from first table with count row from second table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `Users` have 5 rows, but when we use this query in result we see only one.

We would like get all lines from table `Users` and count `q.Status = 'no'` from table `Quest` for each row. Tell me please how right make it?

```
SELECT
    *,
    ifnull(count(q.Status = 'no'),0) as CountQuestionsNew
FROM 
    Users as u
    LEFT JOIN Quest as q on q.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE 
    u.UserID != '453'
```

Comment: show the code that processes the query please.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT u.*, COALESCE(q.CountQuestionsNew, 0) CountQuestionsNew
  FROM Users u LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT UserID, SUM(status = 'no') CountQuestionsNew
    FROM Quest
   GROUP BY UserID
) q
    ON u.UserID = q.UserID
WHERE u.UserID <> '453'
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71b3d/3)** demo